# WordPress: echo featured image in img tag

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, custom-post-type

i am trying to fetch feature image in page template and print it in bootstrap code block like this

```
    <div class="container">
            <?php
                $args=array('post_type' => 'partner');
                $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
                // Start the Loop.
                while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>                                    

         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <img src="<?php  echo the_post_thumbnail();?>" class="img-responsive"> 
         </div>
      <?php                                
          endwhile;
       ?>

    </div>
```

this is not printing image whats wrong with it please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) already prints the thumbnail...which means you shouldn't use `echo` in combination with it. It also prints the entire `<img />` tag...not the source. Its second parameter is an array of attributes.

Proper usage would look like the following:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Here's how that tag works:

> `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>`
>
> `$size` — Image size (keyword or array of dimensions)
>
> `$attr` — Array of attribute/value pairs.

Read more [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: Perfect , i just  did inspect element after reading  your answer and that   made the whole thing clear . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In this reference, you can also do it by putting image url in href of your img tags. So your complete code will be like this :

```
<div class="container">
<?php
                $args=array('post_type' => 'partner');
                $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
                // Start the Loop.
                while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>                                    

         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="img-responsive"> 
        <?php endif; ?>

         </div>
      <?php                                
          endwhile;
       ?>
</div>
```